# What do I use as the first argument of the apply method if I dont want to change the object used as "this"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use [the `apply` method of a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), and I want to do something special with the `argsArray` parameter, but leave the first parameter as default. Im just not sure how to do that.

What can I put in place of the first parameter to do that?

From what I understand, that first argument can change what `this` points to - I'm trying to figure out how to leave it pointing at the function. This is a naive question, I know, I dont have a good understanding of how this works yet.

If I've asked this wrong or it doesn't makes sense, please comment and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: FYI there's never an intrinsic `this` which can be overridden. Either a function has a  bound `this` value, in which case you can't change it, or it has no associated `this` value, and gets it based on how it's called.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it as ;

```
func.apply(null , args[])
```